# Python Basemap does not show plotted points

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, maps, matplotlib-basemap

I just started using Python basemap, but I can not make point to appear in my map!... Here is the function I'm trying to build:

```
def map_plot(df):

    df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').dropna()
    m = Basemap(projection='mill',
                llcrnrlat=25,
                llcrnrlon=-130,
                urcrnrlat=50,
                urcrnrlon=-60,
                resolution='l') #proyeccion de Miller

    m.drawcoastlines()
    m.drawcountries(linewidth=2)
    m.drawstates(color='b')
    m.fillcontinents(color = '#888888')
    x_map, y_map = m(df['Latitude'].values, df['Longitud'].values)
    x = []
    y = []

    for x_map, y_map in zip(x_map, y_map):
        if y_map > 0: continue
        x.append(x_map)
        y.append(y_map)
    m.plot(x, y, 'g^', markersize=5)
    plt.show()
```

So, the map shows, but not a single point is plotted.
Here is how my data looks before calculating the projection coordinates:

```
,Latitude,Longitud
0,35.93,-77.79
1,35.93,-77.79
2,38.78,-80.22
3,37.65,-82.25
4,41.12,-104.82
5,41.85,-80.83
6,39.7,-84.21
7,39.9,-80.94
8,39.1,-84.54
9,39.93,-83.82
10,40.05,-82.39
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need grid coordinates (x, y) to plot points on the map. Here is the code that implements the required coordinate transformation and does the plotting.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = Basemap(projection='mill',
                llcrnrlat=20,
                llcrnrlon=-130,
                urcrnrlat=50,
                urcrnrlon=-60,
                resolution='l')  # Miller proj, USA

m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawcountries(linewidth=2)
m.drawstates(color='b')
m.fillcontinents(color = '#888888')

# sample data to plot with
lons = [-100, -75]  # degrees
lats = [25, 40]

# plotting points
for lon, lat in zip(lons, lats):
    x, y = m.projtran(lon, lat)        # coord transformation      
    m.plot(x, y, 'r^', markersize=15)  # needs grid coords to plot

plt.show()
```

[image: Output plot]

Answer (score 0):

Your line

```
if y_map > 0: continue
```

is causing you problems. Every value of y is >0, so the `continue` is being applied, which skips to the next iteration of the `for` loop. Consequently, your lines

```
    x.append(x_map)
    y.append(y_map)
```

are never used

Comment: Thank you hugke729, but sadly that is not the problem, I checked and after that I got the list of coordinates. The data is a mess, but I cleaned it all. Also tryed to plot in google maps, and it worked!, what else could be with this basemap?

Comment: Just noticed that your ``m(df['Latitude'].values, df['Longitud'].values)`` line is wrong. Longitude should be the first argument, not latitude